# How to keep a big hash on disk instead of in RAM?

Tags: perl, ram, disk

I've got too little RAM to finish a calculation because of a large hash. Is there a drop-in Perl module that would let me use the hash without keeping it all in RAM? I expect it to top out around 4GB, and I've got a bit less than 2GB available for the script. I don't think processing time or disk I/O would be an issue.

Comment: Look into [tie](https://perldoc.perl.org/perltie#Tying-Hashes), I think this should do what you need. Or use a database. See also [this chapter in Effective Perl](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1582932&seqNum=7).

Comment: Tie is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`dbm_open`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen) to open a hash connected to a [DBM file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBM_(computing)). These are not particularly sophisticated and can handle shallow hashes of simple keys and values.

For anything more sophisticated, I would recommend using [SQLite](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite).

Comment: My hash has string keys, and the values are hash refs with string keys and 0/1 values. Does that mean DBM can't handle it?

Comment: @Anna correct, you can only do one level. You could restructure the hash to be a flat one with combined keys, and it would work — or else use something else :)

Comment: @Anna There's [MLDBM](https://metacpan.org/pod/MLDBM), but at that point it makes sense to jump to SQLite. Or you can restructure your program so you don't have to hold it all in memory.

Comment: I solved it by running the program on another computer:)

Comment: @Anna Have you tried `$hash{$key1,$key2}` syntax? see `$SUBSCRIPT_SEPARATOR` (`$; `) in man perlvar for details.

Comment: @AnFi I hadn't seen that syntax (would have interpreted that as the binary comma operator). How is it relevant to my memory issues?

Comment: @AnFi Aha right, to use DBM of course! Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind for next time I've got that kind of structure! I guess I could also just have done $hash{"$key1-$key2"}

Answer (score 1):

You may try [DB_File](https://perldoc.perl.org/DB_File) module (or similar modules).
Memory usage hints: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=146377

Take a look at [AnyDBM_File](https://perldoc.perl.org/AnyDBM_File) for other similar modules available with rudimentary comparison.

$hash{$key1,$key2} syntax can be used to turn multi level hash into flat (single level) hash.
see [$SUBSCRIPT_SEPARATOR](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$SUBSCRIPT_SEPARATOR) in `man perlvar` for details.